# Nesting buttons in Swift

Tags: swift, button

How can a button press another button. I want to know how to press button2 and have button1 complete its task and relay that information to button2. I feel like this answer is super simple, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!

@IBAction func button1(sender: AnyObject) {
    var textAgeArray = ["1", "2", "3"]
    let randomTextAge = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(textAgeArray.count)))
    let displayAge = textAgeArray[randomTextAge]
    textField1.text = displayAge
}

@IBAction func button2(sender: AnyObject) {
    textField2.text = displayAge 

}
```

Comment: You can move any common operations into a separate function and then call the function from both actions where you can perform any additional action-specific operations. I hope that this makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using these buttons to update particular text field when a button is pressed, so put that task inside a function and then call that function from any button. If you want to track that then add a variable to check what is current text. What you are trying to do can be done through this way because you don't want to press button you want to do particular task.

Comment: Thanks guys! This really helped and completely solved the problem. I knew it was something super simple. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As [Mukesh suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33041775/810167) you can refactor your code, with a separate method of the repeated code.

Just thought I'd post an alternative solution. You can call the `button1` method from inside of `button2`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!

var displayAge: String?

@IBAction func button1(sender: AnyObject) {
    var textAgeArray = ["1", "2", "3"]
    let randomTextAge = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(textAgeArray.count)))
    displayAge = textAgeArray[randomTextAge]
    textField1.text = displayAge
}
@IBAction func button2(sender: AnyObject) {
    button1(sender)
    textField2.text = displayAge
}
```

Note that you must take the `displayAge` variable out so that the `button2` method can access it. This will make `textField1` and `textField2`'s text the same. I'm not sure if that's the desired result as I can't tell from your post. If you want these to be different random fields then I would suggest you refactor it to have the repeated method separate.

This will also set both of the text fields at the same time. If you don't want to refactor your code to only set one field at a time then you could start tagging your button's to see where the call is coming from:

```
@IBOutlet var button1: UIButton!

@IBAction func button1(sender: AnyObject) {
    var textAgeArray = ["1", "2", "3"]
    let randomTextAge = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(textAgeArray.count)))
    displayAge = textAgeArray[randomTextAge]

    // if sender is this button, then update text, otherwise don't do anything
    if sender.tag == 1 {
        textField1.text = displayAge
    }
}
```

By default tags are 0, but you can change them by set them like so: (You can put this in `viewDidLoad`)

```
button1.tag = 1
```

May as well add the solution by refactoring for completeness:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!

@IBAction func button1(sender: AnyObject) {
    let displayAge = randomTextAge()
    textField1.text = displayAge
}
@IBAction func button2(sender: AnyObject) {
    let displayAge = randomTextAge()
    // Uncomment the line below if you want to update textField1 with the same value
    // textField1.text = displayAge
    textField2.text = displayAge
}

func randomTextAge() -> String {
    var textAgeArray = ["1", "2", "3"]
    let randomTextAge = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(textAgeArray.count)))
    let displayAge = textAgeArray[randomTextAge]
    return displayAge
}
```